# Bash Script to Ping Host and make directory

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to 
ping hosts from a file, if it fails on a host move on to the next one and maybe output the failed ones.
On the successfully pinged hosts make a directory. From the host running this 
script. It should be something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
prod.txt=$(/usr/local/bin/prod.txt)
for hosts in $(prod.txt); do
```

I am having issues getting the ping part of it to work
i have the make directory of 
    mkdir -p /var/db/kds >/dev/null 2>&1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that you can adapt to your needs:

```
$ cat /tmp/hosts.txt 
10.10.0.1
10.10.0.2
10.10.0.3
10.10.0.4
10.10.0.5
10.10.0.6

$ cat /tmp/run.sh 
#!/bin/sh

for host in $(cat /tmp/hosts.txt)
do
    if ping -c 2 $host >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        mkdir -p /tmp/path/$host
    else
        echo "$host is down"
    fi
done

$ ./run.sh 
10.10.0.2 is down
10.10.0.3 is down
10.10.0.4 is down


$ ls /tmp/path/
10.10.0.1  10.10.0.5  10.10.0.6
```

Comment: linuxfan, how would modify it so i can create the directory on the hosts if passed pings on.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you want to create a directory on the hosts that are reachable? If so, you need to setup password-less ssh authentication on each host and simply run `'ssh user@$host 'mkdir -p /some/path'`

Comment: linuxfan, thank you i did the password-less ssh auth and it work